# Writing a static method to find grade

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a static method named marksToGrades that takes an array of marks (double) between 1 and 100 as a parameter and returns a String array containing the corresponding grade.

[image]

```
public static String[] marksToGrades(double[] array){
    double[] grades;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (array[i] >= 80 && array[i] <= 100)
        array[i] = "A";
    else if (array[i] >= 65 && array[i] < 80)
        array[i] = "B";
    else if (array[i] >= 50 && array[i] < 65)
        array[i] = "C";
    else if (array[i] >= 0 && array[i] < 50)
        array[i] = "D";
    else array[i] = "Invalid";
    } 
    return grades;
}
```

This the following error I am getting, but I am unsure on how to fix this.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

**Update**

```
public static String[] marksToGrades(double[] array){
    String[] grades;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (array[i] >= 80 && array[i] <= 100)
        grades[i] = "A";
    else if (array[i] >= 65 && array[i] < 80)
        grades[i] = "B";
    else if (array[i] >= 50 && array[i] < 65)
        grades[i] = "C";
    else if (array[i] >= 0 && array[i] < 50)
        grades[i] = "D";
    else grades[i] = "Invalid";
    } 
    return grades;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The error you see is very much explanatory. You attempt to assign a String value in a double array.

Comment: @User426190: Please, copy-paste the text instead of posting the pictures :)

Comment: Next time I'll try to copy-paste the text. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `array` is defined as `double[] array` which means it's an array of double values.

With `array[i] = "A";` you assign a `String` to the array of `double` values, which is not compatible. Simply said, you cant assign a word to the array of decimal numbers.

To fix it, use the `String[] grades` which has been already defined:

```
grades[i] = "A";
```

Also, you need to initialize the array with the same length as the input array.

```
String[] grades = new String[array.length];
```

Comment: Since it was not compatible, I have removed it and replaced it with String[] grades; and returned, but it is giving me another error.

Comment: See the edited answer. You need to initialize the array with the same length. If the input array has ex. `7` items, the `new String[array.length]` will have also `7` items.

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because incompatible types.

You need create a `String[] grades;` as return type:

```
String[] grades = new String[array.length];
```

and assign grade to `grades` like this:

```
grades[i] = "A";
```

Comment: I changed the double[] grades; to String[] grades; and therefore returned that, but I'm getting another error which follows.

Answer (score 0):

The error is simple. You are creating an array, without initializing it. What i mean is:
String []grades; 
means
String []grades = null;

and then, you attempt to access index i of null array. You need to initialize the array with size first, for example:
String[] grades = new String[array.length];